# Renew a function call in the Javascript object

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm new to the Javascript world. I have a problem when I dealing with the object. Here is the code:

```
let mutableValue = 3

const getText = () => mutableValue

const obj = {a: getText()}
```

so far so good, but if I change the value of `mutableValue`, the `obj` won't update its value *(thanks: Tibrogargan, JameelM)*. So I want a way to call the `obj`, such that it will automatically call `getText()` again to renew its value.  Another condition is not to change the external call style of `obj`, because my existing code has utilize `obj.a` everywhere, and they are hard to modify. *(So thanks to the answer of Haowen and JameelM)*

[image: console test result]

Comment: `getText` is a variable that holds a reference to a function.  `getText()` executes the function.  doing `obj = { a: getText() }` creates `obj` sets the value of `obj.a` to the result of calling `getText`.  You cannot "renew" that value.  It's effectively the same as doing `obj = { a: 3 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to reference `mutableValue` from accessing the property `a` like this:

```js
let mutableValue = 3
const obj = { get a() { return mutableValue } }

console.log(obj.a)
mutableValue = 4
console.log(obj.a)
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to mutate you have to keep the value in an object for example

```
let mutatingObject = {
            mutableValue: 3
        };

        const getText = () => mutatingObject ;

        const obj12 = {
            a: getText()
        }

        mutatingObject.mutableValue=4;
        console.log(obj12.a);
```

Now see the output when you update the value of an object , it's mutating.

[image]

This is called **By Reference**. In Javascript when create an object , It will create new address in memory which knows where is my object exactly lives.

When you assign an Object 1 to an another Object 2 , both will share this common memory location. So when you update a property or value in Object 1 will also mutate in Object 2 .

But Primitive type such as boolean,string,number are **By Value**

For example

```
var a=1; (Which has an address location which knows where that primitive value sits in memory)
```

Let's suppose if you assign the value of **a** in to another variable called **b** like below

```
var b=a;
```

In Primitive types the new variable point to a new address in the memory and copy the value of **a** in to it. So if you change again  a = 2 , it will not change the value of b , because both are in difference memory location.

https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Answer (score 1):

object -> reference values

try

```
let mutableValue = {aa: 3}

const getText = () => mutableValue

const obj = {a: getText()}
```

run

```
obj.a// {aa: 3}
mutableValue.aa = 4
obj.a// {aa: 4}
```

Comment: haha because I'm changing some existing code write by others, the obj.a should return the same format as before, but still a good way!